# Book says number of leaf nodes for a BDT to be n!... How is it n!?

Tags: sorting, binary-search-tree, lower-bound

Text from the book: "Let us define the external path length of a tree as the sum of the lengths of paths from the root to each of the leaf nodes. Then the average time complexity of a sorting algorithm based on comparisons is equal to the external path length of the binary decision tree corresponding to this algorithm divided by the number of leaf nodes, which is n!". How is the number of leaf nodes n! ?

(Is related to the average case lower bound of Sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This claim appears to assume that all elements are unique (no duplicates). The number of permutations (ordering) of n unique elements is n!, so in a decision tree where each leaf represents a specific ordering of unique elements, there are n! leaves, only one of which represents a sorted ordering.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I was thinking of BDT in the wrong way.